# Create a Dictionary using Array of Object

Tags: java, arrays, dictionary

I have a problem with this code. My purpose is to create a Dictionary that counts the frequency of a word in a text, using an Array of Objects (I can't use Hash Map or something else). I created a class Pair that contains the couple (word,count).

```
public class Pair
{ public String word;
  public int count;

  public Pair(String word,int count)
  {this.word=word;
   this.count=count;
  }

  public String getWord()
  {return word;}

  public int getCount()
  {return count;}


  public void addCount()
  {count++;}



  public String toString()
  { return getWord()+" "+getCount();}

}
```

And the class Dict that creates an Array of object using the Pair class

```
public class Dict

    {   private Pair [] a;
     private int inputSize;


    public Dict()
     {a=new Pair[10];
      inputSize=0;
     }


   public void insert(Pair x)
     { if(a.length==inputSize)
         { Pair newA []=new Pair [2*inputSize];
            for(int i=0;i<inputSize;i++)
                 { newA[i]=a[i];
                 }
                  a=newA;
         }

       for(int i=0;i<inputSize;i++)                 // i check if x is already in the array if i find it i replace it otherwise i add it in the array
          { if(a[i].getWord().equals(x.getWord()))
                {a[i]=x;
                 }
         }

        a[inputSize++]=x;
    }



  public Pair find(Pair x)                             // if i don't find x return null
  { for(int i=0;i<inputSize;i++)
        {  if(a[i].getWord().equals(x.getWord()))
               {return a[i];}

        }
     return null;

  }



  public String toString()
  {String s="";
   for(int i=0;i<inputSize;i++)
       { s=s+a[i].toString()+'\n';
       }
     return s;
  }
}
```

After I created the test class with the main method

```
import java.util.*;
import java.io.*;

public class MyDict
{public static void main(String [] args)
  { Dict d=new Dict();
    Scanner c=new Scanner(System.in);

    while(c.hasNext())
    {String s=c.next();
     Pair p=new Pair(s,1);        // create a new pair
     Pair previous=d.find(p);
     if(previous!=null)           //if the pair is already in the stack i add 1 to the counter otherwise i insert it in the array
       {p.count++;}
       else
      {d.insert(p);}
      s="";

    }

    System.out.println(d);
  }
}
```

But it doesn't work, in particular the variable "count" doesn't grow.
For example, if I write "how how are are you you " I get:

```
how 1
are 1
you 1
```

Can anyone help me please?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change `p.count++` to `previous.count++`.

Otherwise you never change the count of the existing `Pair`s.

```
 Pair p=new Pair(s,1); 
 Pair previous=d.find(p);
 if(previous!=null) {         
     previous.count++;
 } else {
     d.insert(p);
 }
```

Comment: @EdoardoDeGaspari if an answer solved your problem, please mark it as an answer(also when you have more reputations you could upvote the answers.) http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work